# How to know if host support Range headers?

Tags: curl, http-headers

When i tried  `curl -r 0-100` to get a part of document i always got a full html page.Is there a simple way to know if host support **range headers** or don't , so i could use curl range option.

Answer (score 2):

A server signals its support for ranges in the response headers. Look for "Accept-Ranges: bytes" in the response when you send a HEAD or a GET to the site.