# Efficient method to access a partial range of the HTML text of several hundred million web pages

Tags: html, curl

I recently used Curl to download the HTML source text of about 3.5 million web pages. Each page consisted of about 30 kB of text, so the resulting downloads were about 100 GB total, which took about 2.5 days on a bandwidth of 500 kB/sec on my laptop internet connection.

I am now looking at a larger job (potentially 1 to 2 orders of magnitude larger) and am looking for ways to reduce the bandwidth requirements, which would otherwise be on the multi-terabyte scale. As I'm only interested in a few lines of the HTML text of the source HTML of each page, I initially thought the `-r` option (byte-range specifier) of Curl might be solution, but it appears that [many sites do not support "range headers";](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332858/how-to-know-if-host-support-range-headers) as a concrete example, both

```
curl https://www.yahoo.com/ -o File1
```

and

```
curl -r 0-10 https://www.yahoo.com/ -o File2
```

retrieve essentially the same ~370kB document, even though the second line has a range specifier that instructs Curl to only retrieve the first 11 bytes of the target URL.

My question is:

- Is there some utility, or some method, to retrieve only a couple
  specific lines of HTML text from the source code of a given URL, rather
  than downloading the entire source text of each page?
- Is it efficient enough to operate in parallel at a rate of several hundred URL requests per second on a typical PC?

My knowledge of web tools other than Curl is pretty low, as is my knowledge of the structure of website design in general, so any info would probably be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

In short, I don't think there is a graceful, precise solution to your problem.

Basically, most web servers are most efficient at issuing the entire response to a client. Since what you are describing is something of a 'corner-case', most servers have little or no support for it.

One option is to us a programming language to create the request, and read the response stream until you get the information you need, then terminate the connection. Python, for example, has :

```
HTTPResponse.read([amt])
Reads and returns the response body, or up to the next amt bytes.
```

This will save you from having to download the "tail" of the response in some cases.

Regarding the parallelization - it is certainly not taxing for a modern PC to have hundreds of connections open. However, your internet connection will still get saturated, and that will likely be the bottleneck.